# Nehushtan destroyed

Tags: commentaries, chukas

1. Could someone explain to me why we read in Melachim II 2:18 that the brass serpent that Moses had made had been kept al this time?
2. And how or why did the people became to honor it; for until that time the Israelites had been offering sacrifices to it; burning incense.
3. And why was it was called Nehushtan (I know it was called after the Nachash (serpent), or Nechoshet (brass), but does the ending תן teaches us anything about it's deeper meaning?).

Answer (score 1):

[SOURCE of Copied text:](https://www.mayim.org.il/?parasha=%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%AA%D7%9F#gsc.tab=0)

וַיַּעַשׂ מֹשֶׁה נְחַשׁ נְחֹשֶׁת וַיְשִׂמֵהוּ עַל הַנֵּס וְהָיָה אִם נָשַׁךְ הַנָּחָשׁ אֶת אִישׁ וְהִבִּיט אֶל נְחַשׁ הַנְּחֹשֶׁת וָחָי: (במדבר כא ט.

Moses made a copper serpent and mounted it on a standard; and when anyone was bitten by a serpent, he would look at the copper serpent and recover. (Bamidbar 21:9)

הוּא הֵסִיר אֶת הַבָּמוֹת וְשִׁבַּר אֶת הַמַּצֵּבֹת … וְכִתַּת נְחַשׁ הַנְּחֹשֶׁת אֲשֶׁר עָשָׂה מֹשֶׁה … וַיִּקְרָא לוֹ נְחֻשְׁתָּן: (מלכים ב יח ד

He abolished the shrines and smashed the pillars and cut down the sacred post. He also broke into pieces the bronze serpent that Moses had made, for until that time the Israelites had been offering sacrifices to it; it was called Nechushtan. (Melachim 2:18:4)

רש"י מלכים ב יח ד "ויקרא לו נחושתן"- לשון בזיון כלומר מה צורך בזה אינו אלא נחש נחושת.

[Rashi ibid] It was called Nechushtan as a name of shame. so to say "what need is there for this, it is merely a copper snake".

משנה מסכת פסחים פרק ד משנה ט

ששה דברים עשה חזקיה המלך, על שלשה הודו לו ועל שלשה לא הודו לו. גירר עצמות אביו על מטה של חבלים והודו לו. **כיתת נחש הנחושת והודו לו**. גנז ספר רפואות והודו לו...

King Hezekiah did six things; about three of them [the Sages] conceded to him and about three they did not concede to him: He dragged the bones of his father on a bier of cords [or ropes], and they conceded to him; **he crushed the brazen-serpent [to be broken to pieces], and they conceded to him;** he hid the Book of Healings, and they conceded to him...(MISHNAH PESACHIM 4:9)

מסכת עבודה זרה דף מד עמוד א

אמר להן רבי יוסי: והלא כבר נאמר: "וכתת נחש נחושת אשר עשה משה"! אמרו לו: ... **אלא כיון דחזא דקא טעו ישראל בתריה, עמד וכיתתו**.

Rabbi Yosei said to them: But isn’t it already stated: “And he broke into pieces the brazen serpent that Moses had made; as until those days the children of Israel sacrificed to it” (II Kings 18:4)...

The Rabbis said to him: ...since Hezekiah saw that the Jewish people were straying after it, he arose and demolished it. (Avoda Zara 44a)

מסכת חולין דף ו עמוד ב

דרש להן מקרא זה: "וכתת נחש הנחושת אשר עשה משה כי עד הימים ההמה היו בני ישראל מקטרים לו ויקרא לו נחושתן" (מלכים ב יח ד). אפשר בא אסא ולא ביערו, בא יהושפט ולא ביערו? והלא כל עבודה זרה שבעולם אסא ויהושפט ביערום! אלא מקום הניחו לו אבותיו להתגדר בו,

תוספות מסכת שבת דף נו עמוד ב

לא שייך למימר הכא מקום הניחו לו אבותיו להתגדר בו כדאמר בפ"ק דחולין (דף ז. ושם:) גבי נחש נחשת שביער חזקיה **דהתם לא ביערוהו אבותיו שהיו יראים לבערו לפי שעשאו משה על פי הדבור**

פסיקתא זוטרתא (לקח טוב) בראשית פרק יז

וכן מצינו כי חזקיהו מלך יהודה כיתת נחש הנחושת אשר עשה משה – "כי בעוד הימים ההם היו ישראל מקטרים לו ויקרא לו נחושתן" (מלכים ב יח ד). ראה משה תיקנו להיות לאות בישראל לזכור נסי אלהינו. וכל השנים שעברו מימות משה ועד חזקיהו לא כיתתו אדם לא מלך ולא נביא עד שבא חזקיהו. וכמה ביערו אסא ויהושפט ושאר הצדיקים, מבערי האשרות והבעלים, איך לא כיתתו זה הנחש? ועוד, כמה עתידות אמר משה רבינו ולא היה יודע כי ישראל עתידין להקטיר לו, ולמה הניחו להיות מכשול לישראל? אלא כך דרך העולם, זה בדורו, וזה בדורו, וכולן המשרתים את אלוהינו באמת נקראים עבדיו. ואין דור אחד יכול לתקן כל הדורות, אלא בכל דור ודור שרי ישראל מודיעין לעם ה' דרך ה' ומתקנין ומחדשין ומוסיפין על הראשונים על דרך עבודת אלוהינו.

[I hope to continue translation, and maybe summary at a later time. Anyone who wishes to do so, in my stead, is cordially welcome to do so].